# How to clean the VSZ on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: java, jmeter, performance-testing, java-server

I'm running JMeter 3.1 on an Ubuntu EC2 instance. Java server needs a lot of memory. Java server always has the same VSZ, Killing or rebooting the instance does not help.

```
USER       PID %CPU %MEM    VSZ   RSS TTY      STAT START   TIME COMMAND
user       5577  334  4.2 11044208 693928 pts/2 Sl+  14:09  38:24 java -Xms512m -Xmx6144m -XX:NewSize=512m -XX:MaxNewSize=6144m....
```

Comment: Why does it bother you that Java is using virtual memory? which problem are you trying to solve? BTW having same value for `Xmx` and `MaxNewSize` is like not having `MaxNewSize` defined at all...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your JVM memory configuration is wrong anyway :

> -XX:MaxNewSize=6144m

should be lower than heap size:

> -Xmx6144m

See:

- http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/hotspotfaq-138619.html

Another point, ensure your heap does not exceed available memory on your instance, but as you don't give type of EC2 instance, we cannot answer.